# R Plotly Choropleth Hover Text Number

Tags: r, plotly

Using this code:

```
    library(plotly)
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_us_ag_exports.csv")
df$hover <- with(df, paste(state, '<br>', "Beef", beef, "Dairy", dairy, "<br>",
                           "Fruits", total.fruits, "Veggies", total.veggies,
                           "<br>", "Wheat", wheat, "Corn", corn))
# give state boundaries a white border
l <- list(color = toRGB("white"), width = 2)
# specify some map projection/options
g <- list(
  scope = 'usa',
  projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
  showlakes = TRUE,
  lakecolor = toRGB('white')
)

plot_ly(df, z = total.exports, text = hover, locations = code, type = 'choropleth',
        locationmode = 'USA-states', color = total.exports, colors = 'Purples',
        marker = list(line = l), colorbar = list(title = "Millions USD")) %>%
  layout(title = '2011 US Agriculture Exports by State<br>(Hover for breakdown)', geo = g)
```

Is there a way to remove the seemingly-random number that appears before the value of df$hover when hovering?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try "hoverinfo = 'text'" in your plot_ly call.

Comment: BTW, the number is the z value. Total exports in this case.